# Stripping "pattern" formatting from text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I remove/modify the "pattern" text property in Microsoft Word text styles? I can't find where it is defined anywhere.

[image: MS Word style formatting dialogue]

Answer (score 2):

In *Format* go to *Border* and it will open a window with three tabs, the last one is *Shading*:

[image]

Change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's surprisingly hard to spot! Oddly, the formatting in my document appears to apply at the character level, not the paragraph level, and I cannot change that in this dialog (the "Apply to" dropdown doesn't list any other options). I get the sense that the file I've inherited is just corrupted.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the formatting applied at the paragraph level. If only some words in Normal-style paragraphs are shaded, it likely means that someone manually cleared the formatting from the other the words (e.g. by selecting No Color in the Shading drop-down on the Home tab > Paragraph group). The file isn't necessarily corrupted; more likely, it has just been worked on by many people over time, some with limited proficiency in Word. If text shouldn't be shaded by default, do what jcbermu suggested. You might then have to select shaded text and press Ctrl+Space to clear the formatting.